# Wordpress | If there any plugins to create things like those

Tags: wordpress

I have this styles created in dynamic page with pure html, css, some js libraries. I want to add it to wordpress theme, If there any plugins can create those styles, or how can i add the code by myself ?
[Style1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut9TJ.png)
[Style2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaZN7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add your own styles:

1) Create a child-theme
2) Add your styles to the child theme
3) Setup the child theme lo load the parent's styles.
4) If you use different css files for the added styles, load them after the child-theme's style.css is loaded.
5) For the js files you will do the same as for css files.

To load child-themes you will need make changes to the `functions.php` of the child-them in order to hook into **wp_enqueue_scripts** action.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_aditional_styles' );
```

and use `wp_enqueue_style();`

```
function oad_aditional_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_style_1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/Style1.css', array(), all );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_style_2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/Style2.css', array(), all );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'MuJsFile.js', array(),null, true );
}
```

(This assumes Style1.css and Style2.css are in the root of the child-theme, otherwise you need to add the corresponding folders to the file name)

For js files, the empty array indicates no dependancies, but if you have dependancies like jQuery, the jquery handle has to be added there.

Comment: Can i add some html and js code to the theme and how?

Comment: I have added some lines for the js files. The html I asume you will add it in the page itself, or otherwise you will need to override existing themplates in the child theme,  or create new templates there that include your html, and then assign the template to a page.

Comment: Thanks @Juan a lot